# Nginx GET return 200 - 955! What does the 955 mean?

Tags: nginx

Hey Im using Nginx as reverse proxy and some of my requests show: `[13/Feb/2019:21:18:32 +0000] "GET /" 200 955 "-" "-" "-"` what does 955 mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the default logfile format, that will be `$body_bytes_sent` which is the size of the returned content in bytes. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) for details.